# Entropy of this system

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

We have a system with two energy states $E_0$< $E_1=0$. We also know that state $E_0$ can only take at most $m$ particles. Curently, there are $n<m$ particles in $E_0$.

Now, I am supposed to answer the following question.

What is the entropy of this system?

What is the derivative of the entropy with respect to $F:=n E_0$?

My idea for the first question is that it is just $S = k_B ln(\binom{m}{n})$, but I am a little bit puzzled about the second one, as there is no $E_0$ occuring in my equation that I could differentiate.
Would you at least agree with my entropy definition in this case?

Comment: For the second point, remember $\frac{d}{d(nE_0)}= \frac{1}{E_0} \frac{d}{dn}$...

Comment: But note that if the temperature of your system is not zero, then the energies $E_0$ and $E_1$ had better appear in the entropy. This is easily understandable : at zero temperature, all the particules are in the ground state, while at very high temperature the energy difference between the two levels is irrelevant, the particles will occupy the two levels. And of course if the function being differentiated depends on $E_0$, the formula given in the commentary above needs more care.